# How to remap `alt gr` + `j` to another key (xkbmap)

Tags: xkb

I use `setxkbmap dk`.

I need the `alt gr` + `j` combination mapped to a character that isn't already included in the layout. At the moment, `alt gr` + `j` maps to nothing.

The reason why I want to do this is so that I can map the character code (of whatever character `alt gr`+`j` produces) to something in vim, [using this technique](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2363/33463).

Answer (score 2):

the quick way would be modifying the`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dk` file, while the more complex would be creating a new layout and not mess too much with these default files.

you can add the your customization in the `dk` file such as:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "latin(type2)"

    name[Group1]="Danish";

    key <AE11>  { [      plus,   question,    plusminus, questiondown ] };
    key <AE12>  { [dead_acute, dead_grave,          bar,    brokenbar ] };

    key <AC10>  { [        ae,        AE,   dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AC11>  { [    oslash,  Ooblique, dead_circumflex, dead_caron ] };
    key <TLDE>  { [   onehalf,   section, threequarters,    paragraph ] };

    key <BKSL>  { [apostrophe,   asterisk, dead_doubleacute, multiply ] };

    key <LSGT>  { [      less,    greater,    backslash,      notsign ] };

    // customization
    key <AC07>  { [         j,          J,    VoidSymbol, VoidSymbol  ] };
    // end of customization


    include "kpdl(comma)"

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

change VoidSymbol for the symbols you want to get. For a list of symbols, [look here](https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap)

if you are going to include more customization, you can follow the same structure as those files found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` by:

1. create a new file such as `cust`
2. create a partial definition such as

```
partial alphanumeric_keys xkb_symbols "vim" {

 // add your customization here

};
```

3. in the dk file (or in your custom file if you start one from scratch) add

```
include "cust(vim)"
```

as you probably realized, you can do in different ways. the "recommended is to create from scratch and leave the default ones unmodified (they might get, overwritten in a system update, for example).  I personally prefer to create a custom files and "include" in the default files because it is easier, for example, to find and change layouts using e.g. gnome settings. And, in case the file gets overwritten, i just need to add "include x(y)" and it is all set...